# how to execute bash script with crontab in centos?

Tags: bash, cron, mysql

My bash file is not executed by cronjob created as root. The cronjob setup looks as it follows

```
0 0 * * * mysql_backup.sh
```

does need to be decalared with the bash command `0 0 * * * bash mysql_backup.sh` ? if I execute manually my bash script manually `sudo bash mysql_backup.sh` than it's working.

I have been creating the cronjob using `sudo crontab u root -e` and the bash file is in the root of centos

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you need to use full path like:

```
0 0 * * * /path/to/mysql_backup.sh
```

Second, you need to make sure your script has execute permission or you can invoke it using:

```
0 0 * * * /bin/bash /path/to/mysql_backup.sh
```

Third, you need to make sure you are executing your cron job with enough privilege.

Comment: thank you for your feedback I have been trying out the following but to cronjob does not execute the bash if I use the following command 0 0 * * * /mysql_backup.sh

Answer (score 0):

also, you could add the following command in the first line of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

(assuming bash is located in /bin/bash). This will make your script run by bash even when called directly, and not as a parameter of the bash.

You could add some logging and also check your crontab log, to see if there is any error that could lead you to the solution.